# UIImageView picture does not change

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to write some code which receives udp packets of images and displays them on a UIImageView. Below is some code I wrote:

```
    NSData *dataIn = [NSData dataWithBytes:packet length:len];
    UIImage *imageIn = [UIImage imageWithData:dataIn];
    [self.Display setImage: imageIn];
    [self.Display setCenter: self.view.center];
    [self.Display setNeedsDisplay];
```

Display is an IBOutlet to the imageview. Now the first image can be displayed on the screen but the image is not updated when new packets are received. I checked the server side and images are sent out correctly. Someone has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, have you verified dataIn has indeed received new data correctly?

Comment: @user523234 I have checked that. It seems like I can receive new data.

Answer (score -1):

`[self.Display setNeedsDisplay];`
 won't work here

when your data arrives in that method: call below:

```
[self.Display setImage: imageIn];
```

again to **refresh** the imageview

Comment: @NANNAV Can you explain a little more? I think I have set image in the above code. And why won't setNeedsDisplay work at that position?